# Illustrator Smart Guide function not working in a specific document

Tags: adobe-illustrator, guides

I have smart guides enabled in this Illustrator document: http://oieho.dothome.co.kr/123.ai

But they aren't working. Why aren't smart guides working?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because first of all, this is tech support as it is about a single document. Secondly, we have no guarantee a link does not contain a virus or other malevolent code, let alone a document we would need to download. Therefore, this question as it stands cannot be answered by this community, nor any other community on the network (like Super User).

Answer (score 3):

You have "Snap to Grid" turned on, which you can't use smart guides with.

From the Adobe help:

> Note: When Snap To Grid or Pixel Preview is turned on, you can't use Smart Guides (even if the menu command is selected).
>
> https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/rulers-grids-guides-crop-marks.html#smart_guides

Comment: thanks to you for your answer i solve this problem. have a good day. :)